# How Threads are executed?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
//Thread priorities

public class Thread_9 implements Runnable {

    static Thread th;
    public void run() 
    {
        th.currentThread();
        System.out.println(th.getName());
    }

    public static void main(String t[])
    {
        Thread_9 obj_1=new Thread_9();
        th=new Thread(obj_1,"Thread_1");
        th.start();
        Thread_9 obj_2=new Thread_9();      
        th=new Thread(obj_2,"Thread_2");
        th.start();
    }

}
```

OUTPUT : -

```
Thread_2
Thread_2
```

Why the output is not

```
Thread_1
Thread_2
```

because I called start function twice, first by obj_1 with name "Thread_1" and then by obj_2
with name "Thread_2".

Comment: th is useless just use the Thread(Runnable) constructor!

Comment: -1. Your real problem is not with theads so it is not a good question.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `static` so basically there is only one `Object` reference associated with `th`, namely the last one assigned. To get individual thread outputs you would need to use separate thread instances

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadTest(), "Thread_1");
        th.start();
        Thread th2 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(), "Thread_2");
        th2.start();
    }
}
```

Note: a race condition can still occur in the event where `Thread_2` becomes available first

Comment: +1 It's important to note that with this mechanism you could get `Thread_2` _before_ `Thread_1` because of race conditions.

Comment: Uh the lock doesn't help @Reimeus.  The race still exists.  I would remove the lock and just note the race condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
public class Runnable_9 implements Runnable {

    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String t[])
    {
        Runnable_9 obj_1=new Runnable_9();
        Thread th1=new Thread(obj_1,"Thread_1");
        th1.start();
        Runnable_9 obj_2=new Runnable_9();      
        Thread th2=new Thread(obj_2,"Thread_2");
        th2.start();
    }
}
```

and it does what you're expecting:

```
$ java Runnable_9
Thread_1
Thread_2
```

Among other things, your `th.currentThread();` statement doesn't *do* anything; it returns a reference to the current thread, but you discard it.

Answer (score 0):

This call is basically meaningless:

```
th.currentThread();
```

Try using it in your print statement:

```
System.out.println(th.currentThread().getName());
```

Then, even though you have a static thread, you will get Output

```
Thread_1
Thread_2
```

Comment: `currentThread()` is `static` show that should be `Thread.currentThread()...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Thread_9 implements Runnable {

    static Thread th;

    public void run() {
        th.currentThread();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); // <<
    }

    public static void main(String t[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread_9 obj_1 = new Thread_9();
        th = new Thread(obj_1, "Thread_1");
        th.start();
        Thread_9 obj_2 = new Thread_9();
        th = new Thread(obj_2, "Thread_2");
        th.start();
    }
}
```

This happens because in case `th.getName()` you just getting the name of referenced Thread, which becomes "Thread_2" before "Thread_1" reaches it. You can check this:

```
public class Thread_9 implements Runnable {

    static Thread th;

    public void run() {
        th.currentThread();
        System.out.println(th.getName()); // << Your example code
    }

    public static void main(String t[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread_9 obj_1 = new Thread_9();
        th = new Thread(obj_1, "Thread_1");
        th.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000); // << Here
        Thread_9 obj_2 = new Thread_9();
        th = new Thread(obj_2, "Thread_2");
        th.start();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Thread_1
Thread_2
```

Also it is a good style to call static methods on class not object:
instead of this: `th.currentThread();` use this: `Thread.currentThread();`

Comment: Please explain what you are doing instead of just dropping in code.